# Modify magento 2 full-text catalog search and filters with my own set of products and filters

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch, search-result

I have a set of SKUs which I want to display in the search result and the filters should be displayed according to my set of SKUs.

For this I have override the `Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Search` class in `etc/di.xml`

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Search"
            type="Mirror\Catalogexport\Model\Layer\Search"/>
```

In the file

```
Mirror\Catalogexport\Model\Layer\Search.php
```

I have override `getProductCollection()` and `prepareProductCollection($collection)` functions.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

namespace Mirror\Catalogexport\Model\Layer;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory as AttributeCollectionFactory;

class Search extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Search
{
    /**
     * Catalog product visibility
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility
     */
    protected $productVisibility;

    /**
     * Catalog config
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config
     */
    protected $catalogConfig;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Search\Model\QueryFactory
     */
    protected $queryFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\ContextInterface $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\StateFactory $layerStateFactory
     * @param AttributeCollectionFactory $attributeCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $catalogProduct
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
     * @param \Magento\Search\Model\QueryFactory $queryFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\StateFactory $layerStateFactory,
        AttributeCollectionFactory $attributeCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $catalogProduct,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Search\Model\QueryFactory $queryFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->queryFactory = $queryFactory;
        $this->productVisibility = $productVisibility;
        $this->catalogConfig = $catalogConfig;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $layerStateFactory,
            $attributeCollectionFactory,
            $catalogProduct,
            $storeManager,
            $registry,
            $categoryRepository,
            $data);
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve current layer product collection
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
     */
    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        if (isset($this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()])) {
            $collection = $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()];
        } else {
            $collection = $this->collectionProvider->getCollection($this->getCurrentCategory());
            $this->prepareProductCollection($collection);
            $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()] = $collection;
        }

        return $collection;
        //return parent::getProductCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize product collection
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer
     */
    public function prepareProductCollection($collection)
    {
        $category = $this->getCurrentCategory();`
        //List of SKUs which I want to show in search result`
        $productSkus = ["MH01","24-WB02","24-MB01","STITCHED-TEE-01","SP7475024-XL"];
        $productImplode = implode("','", $productSkus);
        $prodAttr = $this->catalogConfig->getProductAttributes();
        $logger->info(json_encode($prodAttr));
        $collection
            ->addAttributeToSelect($this->catalogConfig->getProductAttributes());
        $collection->getSelect()
            ->where('sku IN (?)', $productSkus)
            ->order("FIELD(sku,'" . $productImplode . "')");
        $collection
            ->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addUrlRewrite()
            ->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSearchIds());
        //$collection->addSearchFilter($this->queryFactory->get()->getQueryText());
        //$collection->addCategoryFilter($category);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

It is not returning any product. If I remove comment then the `$collection->addCategoryFilter($category);` then it is displaying my set of products but filters and sorting is not working properly.

If I remove comment from

```
$collection->addSearchFilter($this->queryFactory->get()->getQueryText());
```

then magento default search result is displayed.

Is there any better way to display our custom search result in magento 2 instead of magento default search?